# How to process a command asking for inputs with an Ansible task?

Tags: ansible

I'm learning Ansible and I'm wondering how to write a task to process the following command:

```
$<command> <options>

  username:
  email address:
  password:
  password (check):
```

The `<command> <option>` asks for four variables that can be hardcoded in the playbook.

Thank you for any insight you can provide

Comment: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/expect_module.html ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`expect`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/expect_module.html) module:

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - expect:
        command: command option
        responses:
          username: "John Doe"
          email: "joh@doe.com"
          password: "mypass"
```

Comment: Thank you and sorry for the late reply. I tested your solution with a standard 'command: passwd <username>' and it works. Unfortunately my 'command option' returns a warning text before asking for an input and so the task crashes. Do you know how I could solve it?

Comment: @konstantin what to do when you want to give input to a shell, expect dont support shell right????

Comment: How would you do it if you want it to prompt for the password so I don't have to hardcode the password in the script?

Comment: I avoid prompts in playbooks. Pass variables via `-e` or via environment variables or some other lookups.