# In Ansible Expect Module, how to ignore warning text showing before responding to prompts?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

thanks to the reply provided to my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38264206/how-to-process-a-command-asking-for-inputs-with-an-ansible-task/38267574#38267574), I learned about the Expect module. In my Ansible playbook, I use it to execute a command and to respond to prompts.  My issue now is that my `command` returns to stdout a warning text before prompting for username, email and password. The expect task then fails, I guess because it does not now what to do with this line of text.

My **playbook.yml**

```
  - expect:
        command: geonode createsuperuser
        responses:
          username: 'test'
          email: 'test@whatever.com'
          password: 'test'
```

The failure report:

```
TASK [expect] ******************************************************************
fatal: [node1]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "geonode createsuperuser", "delta": "0:00:30.129827", "end": "2016-07-28 09:39:57.806523", "failed": true, "rc": null, "start": "2016-07-28 09:39:27.676696", "stdout": "Not enabling BingMaps base layer as a BING_API_KEY is not defined in local_settings.py file.\r\nUsername: ", "stdout_lines": ["Not enabling BingMaps base layer as a BING_API_KEY is not defined in local_settings.py file.", "Username: "]}
```

Unfortunately I can't disable the warning at this stage of the configuration.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: Voting to close this because it's obvious from the error that you're just missing the casing.

Comment: Ah no sorry to be a newby, it was not obvious to me. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Response search phrases are case sensitive!
Use:

```
responses:
  Username: test
```

or:

```
responses:
  (?i)username: test
```

Comment: Ups sorry, I did not realize that was such a simple error, not a big clue in the error message. From now on I'll never forget! Thank you